# Why http server is dropping connections even when the server isn't under high load?

Tags: http, server, httpserver

I experimented with a web server and noticed that it's dropping connections even when the server isn't under high load. What could be the reasons for this behavior?

context: I saw numerous videos on youtube with people talking about the fact that nodejs "does not scale" and so on. Personally I don't care much. I'll use whatever is easier (I know it uses less memory and cpu but a small website doesn't need that much anyways). But out of curiosity I tried to replicate their tests.

So I started an ec2 with 1 core and 1GB ram.

I built a small server with just one endpoint — not much; it has a single route that takes a request, and returns a JSON response with the current time, and a small string. This is bare minimum. (The plan was to test something with external api calls, a database, some file handling and so on. But stoped here because I encountered issues)

I built this in node, go and rust. However, when I tried to test it, none of them worked.

I used my pc as a client. I tried to fier 1000 requests at once.. No problem (it took 600ms). Then I tried again (it took a bit longer 1.2s). no problem. then I tried again and half of them failed. And so one. Sometimes it took 30 seconds to complete.

I made a script that was firing 300 requests at once then wait 1s.

It worked for 10-30s or so and then it starts to drop connections. Or paused for a while doing (nothing? I don't know what happed) then continuing.

The cpu was barely used, CPU was under 10% and the memory was 15MB for go and about 60MB for node. But then... where is the bottleneck?

I tried to use ab for testing but I got similar results. Sometime it work without issues and sometimes I got "apr_socket_recv: Connection reset by peer 54".

By the way, the same issue occurred with all of them. From the client's perspective, there was no difference between them. The failure rate and response timings were practically identical.

This blows my mind because I was expecting the ec2 to handle few thousands requests per second without any issues. It doesn't do anything after all.

Can someone explain to me what is going on and what I did wrong?

here is the code I used

```js
    async function healthCheckerHandler(req, res) {
        const MESSAGE = "Build Simple CRUD API with Node";

        const response = {
            status: "success",
            message: MESSAGE,
            now: new Date()
        };
        
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.end(JSON.stringify(response));
    }

    const server = http.createServer(async (req, res) => {
        if (req.method === 'GET' && req.url === '/api/health') {
            await healthCheckerHandler(req, res);
        } else {
            res.statusCode = 404;
            res.end('Not Found');
        }
    });

    server.listen(PORT, '0.0.0.0', () => {
        console.log(` Server started successfully`);
    });
```